# SQLalchemy(MySQL): Exception during reset or similar - Lost connection to MySQL server during query

Tags: python, mysql, pandas, sqlalchemy

I am running a 6-minute-long read query.

```
source_connection = source_db_connection.connect().execution_options(stream_results=True, max_row_buffer=1000)

for df_from_db in pd.read_sql_query(raw_data_query_pandas, source_db_connection, params=(...), chunksize=1000)
```

And getting the following error:

```
    Exception during reset or similar
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "%PATH%\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool\base.py", line 986, in _finalize_fairy
    fairy._reset(
  File "%PATH%\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool\base.py", line 1432, in _reset
    pool._dialect.do_rollback(self)
  File "%PATH%\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\default.py", line 692, in do_rollback
    dbapi_connection.rollback()
  File "%PATH%\venv\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\connection_cext.py", line 538, in rollback
    self._cmysql.rollback()
_mysql_connector.MySQLInterfaceError: Lost connection to MySQL server during query
```

Tried connection params: pool_recycle=240, pool_pre_ping=True, poolclass=NullPool

Comment: That will not help as you must first optimize your query and if necessary increase the timeouts

Comment: @nbk: What timeouts are you please referring to?

Comment: See https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/engines.html#use-the-connect-args-dictionary-parameter

Comment: And https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/gone-away.html

Answer (score 0):

I changed the logic to:

```
for df_from_db in pd.read_sql_query(raw_data_query_pandas, source_connection, params=(...), chunksize=1000):
    df_from_db.to_csv(filename, index=False, mode='a', header=False)
```

and the errors are gone.